# how to add id value from javascript in the form url?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

"When clicking the link, javascript we take an id from date attribute, and we add it in the form, and we display a modal window."

How to add id value from javascript in the form?

link:

```
= link_to _('Report this'), '#', class: 'report', data: { comment_id: comment.id,   toggle: 'modal', target: "#report_reasons"}
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $(".comments").on("click", ".comment a.report", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var commentId = $this.data("comment-id");
  });
});
```

form:

```
= simple_form_for(Report.new, url: report_video_comment_path(video.id, 2), remote: true) do |f|
```

instead of 2, it is necessary to insert data-attr from javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better maintain a hidden field in the form as id and set the value using JavaScript. I guess you can do that comfortably.

```
= simple_form_for(Report.new, url: report_video_comment_path(video.id, 2), remote: true) do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :comment_id
```

In JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $(".comments").on("click", ".comment a.report", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#report_comment_id').val($(this).data("comment-id"));
  });
});
```

Comment: for example? how it shall look?

Comment: Thanks, what to do to me with 2?
url: report_video_comment_path (video.id, 2).
instead of 2 shall be comment.id

Comment: as you are using nested routes , you have to have 2 parameters there. use 2 there as dummy and in controller use params[:report][:comment_id] to get that actual comment